# Using address function to create array excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to create an array using address to find the max value from a different sheet

```
=address(10,15,1,true,"othersheet")&":"&"address(11,20,true,"othersheet")
```

returns this `othersheet!$O$10:othersheet!$T11`

this returns the correct address for the array but it is not useable as it is. Indirect causes #ref error. Max causes #Value error

If I copy paste `othersheet!$O$10:othersheet!$T11` into a different cell as a value, then take the max of it `=max(othersheet!$O$10:othersheet!$T11)` it works fine.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong

Comment: I think your correct formula is `=ADDRESS(10;15;1;TRUE;"othersheet")&":"&ADDRESS(11;20;1;TRUE;"othersheet")` that returns `othersheet!$O$10:othersheet!$T$11` ;).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `INDIRECT()` like this:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(10;15;1;TRUE;"othersheet")):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(11;20;1;TRUE;"othersheet")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this 7 year old post because I have a different answer with a similar problem, took me a while to figure out how to make this work for some other formulas.

When I use `MATCH()` using `ADDRESS()` and any combination of `INDIRECT()` to create an array it returns a `#VALUE` error

```
MATCH(A1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1,,,"othersheet"))&":"&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,10,,,"othersheet")),0)
```

Or

```
MATCH(A1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1,,,"othersheet")&":"&ADDRESS(1,10,,,"othersheet")),0)
```

Both return `#VALUE`

But if I use it with an `INDIRECT(ARRAYTOTEXT())` it seems to work:

```
MATCH(A1,INDIRECT(ARRAYTOTEXT(ADDRESS(1,1,,,"othersheet")&":"&ADDRESS(1,10))),0)
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).